# .NET inherited label doesn't autosize

Tags: vb.net, winforms, label

I'd like to inherit from *Windows.Forms.Label*, so I've made something like that:

```
Public Class CustomLabel
    Inherits Label

    Public Property CustomText As String

    Protected Property DefaultText as 

    Public Overrides Property Text As String
        Get
            Return If(CustomText <> "", CustomText, MyBase.Text)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The issue is using this, even if AutoSize property is still true, the label keep it's original size whatever the value set to CustomText.

So I thought that Mybase.Text property isn't updated when CustomText is set to I've changed to :

```
Public Class CustomLabel
    Inherits Label

    Public Property CustomText As String
        Get
            Return _txt
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _txt = value
            MyBase.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected _txt As String

    Protected Property DefaultText As String

    Public Overrides Property Text As String
        Get
            Return If(CustomText <> "", CustomText, DefaultText)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            DefaultText = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

But still the same issue.

And, on the other side, when I set the Text property on a standard Label in the same place in the code where I set my CustomLabel, the autosize works.

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some other tries, I've check how the *TextChanged* event is raised. It appears that the control is firstly initialized by the designer, and the *CustomText* is set to nothing, and as expected the *TextChanged* event is raised.

However, later in the code when *CustomText* property is set to the wanted value, I don't know why, but the event is not raised, even if the string is strictly different.

So to get a working code I have to write:

```
Public Property CustomText As String
    Get
        Return _txt
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _txt = value
        OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty) 'instead of Mybase.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

To force the event and then trigger the label resize.

So it looks as solved, but if anyone has an explanation, I'd be happy to know it.